# Web-To-Lead Validations

Tags: validation

I have currently created the below web-to-lead form but I am having trouble with a couple things. What code/script would I need to input to ensure the email field does not allow email addresses from gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc...? Also, how do I make certain fields like first name, last name, email, and web site required fields?

-->

                                    -->


First Name

Last Name

Phone

Email

Company

City

State/Province

Website

Answer (score 2):

I used `jQueryValidate` in this in webtocase form; same principles apply for web2Lead (props to @crmprogdev). Took me a few minutes to configure.  Obviously there are more robust solutions out there

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<!--  Jquery Validate plugin for verifying fields are required and of proper  -->
<!--   replace if there's a preferred solution for your website               --> 
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

</head><body><form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" id="web2caseForm" novalidate="novalidate">  <!-- this is the PROD servlet -->

<input type="hidden" name="orgid" value="someorgid">
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="http://mycompany.com/home/contact/thank-you.html">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="youremail.com">                                      -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<p id="caption">Have an issue with our products?  Please fill out the form to file a ticket.</p>
<table>
<tbody><tr><td><label for="name">Contact Name</label></td><td><input id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><label for="company">Company</label></td><td><input id="company" maxlength="80" name="company" size="20" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td><label for="email">Email</label></td><td><input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email"></td></tr>


<tr><td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td><td><input id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="60" type="text"></td></tr>

<tr><td><label for="description">Description</label></td><td><textarea id="description" rows="6" cols="80" name="description"></textarea></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" id="external" name="external" value="1"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<script>
// jQuery validate plugin
// 'name' attribute is required on all input/select DOM elements to be validated 
$("#web2caseForm").validate({
    rules: {
            name : {required: true, minlength: 3},
            company: {required: true, minlength: 3},
            email: {required: true, email: true},
            subject: {required: true, minlength: 10},
            description: {required: true, minlength: 10}
    },
    messages: {
        name: {required: "Please specify your first and last name", minlength: jQuery.validator.format('At least {0} characters')},
        company: {required: "Please specify your company name", minlength: jQuery.validator.format('At least {0} characters')},
        email: {required: "Please provide your email address", email: "Please use a valid email format"},
        subject: {required: "Please provide a subject for your support case", minlength: jQuery.validator.format('At least {0} characters')},
        description: {required: "Please provide a description. Max 32000. No rich text.", minlength: jQuery.validator.format('At least {0} characters')}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("input[name = 'orgid']").attr('value','00Dxxxxxxxxxxxx');  // inject PROD orgId into DOM before submit; avoids simpleton scrapers getting the ID
        form.submit();
    }
}
);  
</script></body></html>
```